# Unable to call click event on ajax button in wicket

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax, wicket

I have a 'save' button, which is an AjaxButton that I am trying to programmatically call the click on. I have a link that I would like to use to call this button's handler. In my AjaxLink, I am appending ajax like so:

`target.appendJavaScript("$('#save-irs1095c-button').click();");`

When this piece of code is called, wicket throws the following exception

[image]

However, when I checked, the behavior is, in fact, enabled. see below:
[image]

So, my question is, what might be causing this error, and is there a way around this to programatically call my 'save' button without an actual click?
I have moved away from the default form processing for my components, so this ajax button now acts as my submittal. Here is the code for the Ajax Button:

```
new AjaxButton("save-modal", coveredForm) {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1975475919740938717L;

    public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> myForm)
    {
        //form submission method

        dataProvider.getIrs1095cSummaryPktManager().save(coveredModel.getObject());

        target.add(EmployeeDetailPanel.this);
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the link I want to click, which will then programatically call said Ajax Button:

```
new AjaxLink<Object>("label-ee-name-link") {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6360058776603040349L;

    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

        EmployeeDetailPanel.this.setEEInfoShowing();

        logr.log(Level.FINER,"save button visible: " + coveredForm.get("save-modal").isVisible());
        logr.log(Level.FINER, "save button enabled: " + coveredForm.get("save-modal").isEnabled());

        List<Behavior> bList = (List<Behavior>)((AjaxButton)coveredForm.get("save-modal")).getBehaviors();

        if(bList != null ? !bList.isEmpty() : false)
        {
            for(Behavior b : bList)
            {
                logr.log(Level.FINER, "Behavior: " + b.toString() + " is enabled: " + b.isEnabled(coveredForm.get("save-modal")));                  
            }
        }

        target.appendJavaScript("$('#save-irs1095c-button').click();");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am checking that the component is visible, enabled, as well as its behavior is enabled.

Here is the html snippet for the Ajax button and followed by the snippet for the link:

```
<div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" wicket:id="back-to-ee-info">Back</button>
    <button id="save-irs1095c-button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" wicket:id="save-modal">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" wicket:id="show-notes-button">Notes</button>
</div>  


<h4 class="modal-title"><a href="" wicket:id="label-ee-name-link"><label wicket:id="emp-name"></label></a></h4>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestion.

Comment: You should really use `isVisibleInHierarchy()` and `isEnabledInHierarchy()` for the Component. Which version of Wicket do you use ?

Comment: Currently using 7.2.0. I am getting false for `isVisibleInHierarchy()`, although I have triple-checked and all parents are visible. There are two main 'containers' on this page, both live at the same level and the one containing the button is visible at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It seems some of the parents of this Component is not visible. Attach the debugger and see which one returns `false` when `isVisibleInHierarchy()` is executed.